# Where do you type in console input in codeblocks?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Apologies in advance for the simple question, but where on earth do you type in input into codeblocks?  I've searched through google, but I can't find anything.
For example, in eclispe, input can typed in via window->show view-> console.  How do I access that in codeblocks?  Thank you.

Cue me looking dumb in 3...2...1...

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11888528/how-to-take-command-line-argument-in-codeblock-10-05)

Comment: @pzaenger that question address how arguments are passed in at runtime, not how to provide input during the execution of the program.

Comment: Do you mean `Menu bar -> Project -> Set program's options`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In CodeBlock when you build and run your code, a new terminal window opens (in windows a new console window) and you can enter your inputs there. it is not like eclipse that you enter your inputs in console view.

Answer (score 0):

Go to <kbd>File</kbd>-><kbd>new</kbd>-><kbd>Project</kbd>-><kbd>Console Application</kbd>.

Type in the name of the project and just click forward to create it.

The project should come premade with a Hello World example. Just run it and you will get the console to appear, that is where you will provide both standard input and output.