# Valgrind on CodeBlocks 13.12

Tags: c, debugging, codeblocks, valgrind

I would like to use **Valgrind on Codeblocks 13.12**, but I was not able to find any easy document to get started.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can add arguments as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11888528/how-to-take-command-line-argument-in-codeblock-10-05 How is that related to Valgrind?

Comment: I added the arguments. I made sure that the path is right but when I press Debug / Continue it just open and close a terminal window. Nothing more....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need the [valgrind](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Valgrind_plugin) plugin for codeblocks.

To install the plugin try this as the root user

```
apt-get install codeblocks-contrib
```

Comment: Thank you very much. How can I get it?

Comment: @dario It depends on what disribution of _Linux_ you are working with.